# PHP While loop array

Tags: php, arrays

Any help is appreciated.
I have an array that is forfetch like this. The reason is to brake down a product in individual arrays. However I can not figure out what statement to put in the while loop so i can loop through each array in $row. initially the statement should be

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

however this was already done to be able to sort the array.

```
$sorted = array_orderby($newarray, 'volume', SORT_DESC, 'edition', SORT_ASC);


foreach($sorted as $row)
{

    while(  ???????   )

{
    $row = build_items($row);



        $template->assign_block_vars('featured_items', array(
            'ID' => $row['id'],
            'IMAGE' => $row['pict_url'],
            'TITLE' => $row['title'],
            'SUBTITLE' => $row['subtitle'],
            'BUY_NOW' => ($difference < 0) ? '' : $row['buy_now'],
            'B_BOLD' => ($row['bold'] == 'y')
        ));
        $k++;
        $feat_items = true;
    }
}
```

Just found the answer. Sorry guys im new at PHP.

```
   foreach($sorted AS $row) {


        $row = build_items($row);

        // time left till the end of this auction 
        $s_difference = time() - $row['starts'];
        $difference = $row['ends'] - time();
        $bgcolour = ($k % 2) ? 'bgcolor="#FFFEEE"' : '';

        $template->assign_block_vars('featured_items', array(
            'ID' => $row['id'],

            'IMAGE' => $row['pict_url'],
            'TITLE' => $row['title'],
            'SUBTITLE' => $row['subtitle'],
            'BUY_NOW' => ($difference < 0) ? '' : $row['buy_now'],
            'BID' => $row['current_bid'],
            'BIDFORM' => $system->print_money($row['current_bid']),
            'TIMELEFT' => FormatTimeLeft($difference),
            'NUMBIDS' => $row['num_bids'],

            'B_BOLD' => ($row['bold'] == 'y')
        ));
        $k++;
        $feat_items = true;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($sorted AS $rows) {
  foreach($rows AS $row) {
  ...
  }
}
```

or with keys/indices

```
foreach($sorted AS $key => $rows) {
  foreach($rows AS $index => $row) {
```

Comment: Is it the same for the  while statement?

Comment: I never use while, does not make any sense. Anyway, you could "nest" while loops the same way.

Comment: I get some odd error when i try to while ($rows AS $row) I dont think this actually works. I edited the post. The original data for this while loop was while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) however since that was done before i need to figure out what a new statement would be.

Comment: I did not actually neaded a while loop anymore

Answer (score 1):

Yes.., we can use **foreach** to print all the values  in an array.

***Example:*** I have an array called "data"  (SQLITE dynamic data). I want to print all the values which are there on "data" array.
By using following sample code  we can print the values in a table format.

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
                                $date = $item['date'];
                                $url = $item['url'];
                                $name = $item['name'];

                            echo"                               
                             <tr>
                                    <td>$date</td>
                                    <td>$name</td>
                                    <td>$url</td>
                                    </tr>
                            ";
                            }
```

Please let me know if i did any mistakes here, sorry for my bad English.